# Ubuntu 22.04 : bluetooth devices are not detected anymore

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I have been using my Microsoft Designer Keyboard and Ergonomic mouse with Ubuntu 22.04 for month. Both bluetooth devices are working fine on Windows too, on a dual boot setup.

Today, I stopped a Windows 10 session and tried to connect both devices on Ubuntu : they are not detected anymore. Like they're blacklisted. Or blocked, as if the unpairing has not been done right.

Or as if they were already paired with another computer, which is not the case. I had a Windows upgrade, is it possible that Windows is locking my mouse and keyboard ?

The bluetooth itself seems to be working; it detects other stuff. If I run `bt-device -l` I get a list of my neighbours devices.

I don't have any lead.

return of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:e0c6]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 17ef:6131 Lenovo Hydra Force Sensor
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e0d8 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 27c6:550a Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 048d:c978 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8258)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0056 Luxvisions Innotech Limited Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Return of `rfkill`

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem came from Windows. There is a Bluetooth option in windows, "fast connect", that kept my devices half paired in windows.

Once I checked of this option, my devices were able to be paired on ubuntu.